# Programs like Chrome and Ms Word have gone a bit animated and slow

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, microsoft-word

Chrome has gone a bit slow when creating/closing tabs, and when playing/pausing youtube videos

Word has when highlighting text with shift and up and down arrows I see it very much.

**ADDED - here is a video(showing chrome's slowness)**  http://ge.tt/api/1/files/227niY92/0/blob?download
(the voice is the voice in the youtube video that is playng, not mine)

Ultimately I restarted Windows and then it was fine, and I can't reproduce it

Comment: Have you verified the system disk is healthy?

Comment: @Ramhound Do you have any suggestions on how you would do that?  The SMART data shown instantly by speedfan, seems to look ok http://i.imgur.com/ZbDNHVu.png  so, would you considewr that healthy or would you do some other test(s), if so, then precisely what test(s)/program(s)?

Comment: @Psycogeek see update i've tried to answer your questions

Comment: @Psycogeek what's the exact name of the flag in chrome://flags that i'm meant to be turning off temporarily?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20729/discussion-between-psycogeek-and-barlop).

Comment: That URL is blocked  by my firewall, so I'm not sure if that will happen to others and whether or not there's an alternate solution for viewing the video.

Comment: @Raystafarian is there an upload site that isn't blocked for you?  so ge.tt is blocked for you? how about wetransfer.com?  fileconvoy.com ?

Comment: I'd say that the reason that this question hasn't gotten attention is because it isn't actually a question. This post simply describes a condition, it doesn't actually **ask** anything.

Comment: @krowe2 Well those that can't figure out what its asking, aren't going to be able to figure out the answer. It has had attention, over 200 views.. But it's such an obscure problem that others haven't run into, that people don't know the answer.  Chris understands what i'm asking, as does psycho. And since I restarted I no longer have it so those that could offer suggestions that might help find what it is, the suggestions are relevant but I can't personally apply them.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your system specs, or really anything coherent about your problem, I'm just going to take a stab in the dark.

I have a pretty good guess as to *what* may have happened. Most likely, some unique set of circumstances (memory errors, computational glitches, bugs, cosmic rays, etc) caused one of two scenarios: an accidental [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), or your system had a memory problem and started [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29). Either one can cause the system to act as if time has slowed down; animations will be slow, and the system will be slow to respond to inputs (mouse, keyboard).

However, I have absolutely no idea *why* it happened. It could be that Chrome ran into a problem (as it often does) and started spawning threads like mad; threads that did nothing but consume CPU cycles. Or you may have run out of RAM, causing the system to offload nearly all memory operations to the pagefile on your HDD (this usually would present differently, though).

Long story short: something deep inside the code went wrong that shouldn't have been able to go wrong. Unfortunately, in Computer Science, *shouldn't be able to* absolutely does not mean *cannot*. It could have been caused by any one of a thousand things; or it could have been caused by the unique combination of ten thousand little things.

Unless you collected significantly more diagnostic information from your system while it was acting abnormally that you forgot to tell us about, it's really not possible to be much more specific. Sorry.

**Edit:** *Useful diagnostic information* ideally includes:

- System Specifications (Required)

  - CPU Model & Frequency
  - RAM type, speed, and size
  - GPU model, RAM size
  - Hard drive information - type, size, speed
  - Network setup
- Runtime information (As much as possible)

  - Running applications
  - Number of threads
  - RAM statistics (allocated, reserved, free)
  - Pagefile information
  - Network traffic statistics
  - A detailed list of running processes and their statistics, using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Unfortunately, there is no terribly easy way to collect this information in a one-click manner. It is very much a question of being very prepared for the next time it happens. Non-reproducible bugs are just the *worst* kind of bugs to diagnose.

Suffice it to say, getting a root cause on this problem is going to take quite a bit of dedication and determination. If this sounds like something you're interested in, I suggest grabbing a copy of the aforementioned [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). Familiarize yourself with it, learn how to use it, and keep it running and ready at all times.

**Edit 2:** To check for memory problems, use the [Windows Memory Diagnostic Utility](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer)

Comment: I doubt it'll happen again for a long time, if at all, but in case it does, can you tell me what diagnostic information would provide the answer. If you check the chat link in the comments of the question you see one person asked for specific diagnostic info which I provided.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some tips. I actually wouldn't expect the SMART data to have any relevance to this particular issue.